# Definite integral question.

Tags: calculus, integration

Use the form of the definition of the integral to evaluate the integral.

$ \int _{ 2 }^{ 5 }{ (4-2x)dx } $

I got to this

$ \int _{ 2 }^{ 5 }{ 4\quad dx } \quad -\quad 2\int _{ 2 }^{ 5 }{ x\quad dx } $

but how can i get $\int _{ 2 }^{ 5 }{ x\quad dx } $ ?

Comment: Do you know of antiderivatives at all?

Comment: "Use the form of the definition..." -- how exactly was definite integral defined?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\int_{a}^{b}xdx = \frac{x^2}{2}\Bigg|^{b}_{a}$

Answer (score 0):

If you draw (either the function $x$ or rather the original) function $f(x)=4-2x$, the area to determine will give you a right triangle with vertices $(2,0)$, $\ (5,-6)$, $\ (5,0)$. As it looks downwards, the integral will be the negative of its area.